# React component using fetch not populating the state from response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

My component fetches some data from YouTube before returning it to the page - trouble is `youtubePlaylistItems` isn't getting populated.

When I try and move `renderYoutubePlaylistItems` into the fetch I get an error about nothing being returned from the component, if I add return null I get nothing back.

As it stands I get an error about `youtubePlaylistItems.map` not being a function.

I've reached a point where I thought I'd ask on here as Google is letting me down.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"


const FetchYoutubePlaylist = (props) => {

 const [youtubePlaylistItems, setYoutubePlaylistItems] = useState([])

 useEffect(() => {

  let endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=" + props.maxResults + "&playlistId=" + props.playlistID + "&key=" + process.env.GATSBY_YOUTUBE_API_KEY

  fetch(endpoint, {
   "METHOD": "GET",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
  })
  .then((response) => {
            // console.log(response)
   return response.json()
  })
  .then((json) => {
            // console.log(json)
   setYoutubePlaylistItems(json)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
   console.log("There was an error: " + error)
  })
 
 }, [props.maxResults, props.playlistID])

 return (

  renderYoutubePlaylistItems(youtubePlaylistItems)

 )

}

const renderYoutubePlaylistItems = (youtubePlaylistItems) => {
 
 let videos = youtubePlaylistItems.map( function(video, index) {
  return <li key={index}>{video.items.snippet.title}</li>
 })

 return (

  <ul>
   {videos}
  </ul>

 )

}

export default FetchYoutubePlaylist
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t set the default value of `youtubePlaylistItems` in useState(), that’s why it's undefined.

You receive response from Google API asynchronously with delay, but before that you call `renderYoutubePlaylistItems` and try to call map from undefined.

Try to set some default value of `youtubePlaylistItems`, useState([]) for example.

Also, are you sure that you get array from API? Check what you get here `response.json()`. It could be that API returns some Object with error, but response status is ok.

Comment: I tried that earlier and didn't have any joy, just added it back in and updated the original post - would anything else have to change for that to work? I thought that was the way to go earlier too...

Comment: Are you sure that you get array from API? Check what you get here response.json(). It could be that API return some Object with error, and response status is ok.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I just needed to sleep on this - the problem was that I was passing the entire json to the map function, not the part of the json I wanted to iterate over... this answer pushed me in the right direction, so have a tick :D

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `"Content-Type": "application/json"`?

Comment: Yeah - I've fixed that but it made no difference to my issue. Thanks for letting me know :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a wrapper on your return, try something like this:

First, add this to your imports:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, Fragment} from "react"
```

And wrap your return, something like this:

```
return (
   <Fragment>
        {renderYoutubePlaylistItems(youtubePlaylistItems)}
   </Fragment>
    )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I comment out the relevant code and replace `{videos}` with `<p>Hi</p>` it renders fine on page, but I'll give this a go just in case :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made any difference, but that's useful to know about - I assume that's used if you don't want a parent container?